# write onkeypress attribute instead of jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everything works here but I need to write the code this way:

`<input type='text' class='inpTitle' data-fn = 'write' onkeypress = "???-what here">`

Any help?

```js
$('.inpTitle').on('keypress', function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13){
let fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');    
window[fn]();
}

});

function write(){
console.log('323');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='inpTitle' data-fn = 'write'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<input type='text' class='inpTitle' data-fn = 'write' onkeypress = "prewrite(this, event)">

function prewrite(obj, e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
  let fn = obj.attr('data-fn');    
  window[fn]();
}

function write(){
  console.log('323');
}
```

Comment: much better, but... maybe one single function is possible

Answer (score 1):

This will

```
<input type="text" data-fn="s" onkeypress="m(this.getAttribute('data-fn'),e)">






  function m(obj,event) {
if(e.keyCode == 13){
    var a=obj.getAttribute('data-fn')
          alert(a);
}
        }
```